# PHPStorm - How to setup live editing

Tags: php, phpstorm

I just got PHPStorm and am having trouble getting the live editing (aka: auto refresh) functioning.  I've got xdebug setup and running.

I've tried googling: https://www.google.com/search?q=phpstorm+live+edit+guide

and found very little that was helpful... How can I setup live editing and ensure it works?

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/LiveEdit **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/05/whats-cooking-instant-htmlcss-editing-preview/ **3)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/liveedit-plugin-features-in-detail/ **P.S.** What xdebug has to do with Live Edit ?

Comment: P.P.S. Apparently plugin bundled with 5.0.1 version had some issues. If it affects you, consider trying EAP build of 5.0.2: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That two links could help:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html

and

- http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/How+to+install+Chrome+extension

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: This second link is what I had to do.

Comment: can i  use the Live File Edit with dynamic File?? I'd like to use it with a Symfony project ... is it possible? in the video i see always html files