# Design yii framework page

Tags: html, css, frameworks, yii, dreamweaver

So, I'm a beginner in this yii framework.
But my job is only too design the view.
I've experienced in designing static webpage using Adobe Dreamweaver. But I can't find how to configure dreamweaver to yii.
What is the best way to design it's view?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about Dreamweavers _design view_? There is no way to "preview" a view because none of the CSS or layouts are loaded, you have to do it in the code view and test it in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not around which IDE or tool to serve your purpose, but you have asked the best way on your problem, then I vote to PHPStorm anyway. In your case, you can use Live Edit.

> It allows you to view your changes in an actual browser window
>   instantly without a page refresh, reload corresponding browser pages
>   (related to opened file in IDE) and highlight corresponding element.
>   Currently only Google Chrome is supported (extensions for Firefox &
>   Safari are still postponed).

See demo

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/liveedit-plugin-features-in-detail/#more-4098

And here is references how to configure LiveEdit

[PHPStorm - How to setup live editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593037/phpstorm-how-to-setup-live-editing?answertab=active#tab-top)