# PhpStorm Live Reload in PHP Files

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is it possible to get live edit or live reload sort of functionality in PhpStorm IDE for PHP projects or PHP files?

Like when I use VSCode, you can do it in just few easy steps using Ritwik's extension of Live Server. It's hassle free. Here, it's such a pain. It seems that each page has to be debugged individually rather than the whole project at one go. Also, no PHP live reload/live edit support?

**EDIT:**
The previous posts regarding this request is for older versions of PhpStorm. Reload in browser option no longer seems to be available in the new version. Hence the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPStorm - How to setup live editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593037/phpstorm-how-to-setup-live-editing)

Comment: It doesn't solve anything. PHPStorm has changed and many old features have been removed it seems.For instance, no reload in browser option seems to be available which actually solves my issue.

Comment: maybe it's me, but this feels like a waste of a feature, everything I have is local so all I need to do is hit F5 in the browser. I know that's not really what you're looking for, but it seems the feature overcomplicates things in general IMO.

Comment: I am going back to VSCode. It's a waste but this ide is not for me. A PHP page should be live editable in a PHP IDE. No excuses. It requires just one extension in VSCode to do so which can be setup in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: @VasuSrivastava what do you mean by live editable? To me it's literally not worth the time, when all you need to do is F5 the page after a change

Comment: I edit the file. I ctrl+s it. The changed code automatically becomes visible in the browser. Live Server type of functionality, I meant.

Comment: @VasuSrivastava I get that - I just can't see why it's needed when you just need to hit one button to see changes? And if it's an ajax request, just reclick the button

Comment: For better workflow, that's all.

Comment: I prefer CPU and RAM dedicated to other resources rather than this feature, just feels pointless imo

Comment: @treyBake Are you joking? Is going back to browser window (alt + tab) and pressing F5 is comfortable for you? When you can just watch to opened browser in another screen just by pressing ctrl + s?

Answer (score 6):

For **PHP Live Editing** (PhpStorm) Try the **Following Steps**:

1. File > Settings > Plugins > Marketplace > [search and install Live Edit] > Apply&OK
2. Run > [Edit Configurations] > [click **+** ] > [select JavaScript Debug]
3. Name:[PHP File Name]>URL:[http://localhost:myport(e.g 8080)/myphpfile.php] > Apply&OK
4. **Important Step** : File > Settings > [Build,Execution,Deployment] > Debugger > Live Edit

   > select [Track changes in files compiled to JavaScript, HTML and CSS] > Apply&OK
5. Run Your File In Debug Mode

[image]

Comment: This is for HTML, JS, and CSS. Not for PHP files

Comment: @briann have you tried it? because I posted what worked for me and at the time I wrote that solution PHP files is what was being rendered. It's a php file mentioned in step 3 above.

Comment: Anyone got it working yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Update** action in **Debug** tool window toolbar:

[image]

does it work for you?

Comment: Nope. It seems it's too much work. I am going to switch back to vscode. A PHP IDE should have live editing feature for PHP pages. Period. Thank God I didn't buy it and thought I would try to evaluate for 30 days. It's headache.

Comment: works for me. Actually, the page is reloaded automatically once I change the code, I don't even need to press *Update*. Can you record a screencast that shows your steps?

Comment: @lena could you walk me through the process. Because I have done exactly what has been stated but my page isn't running. I have done everything but this, I couldn't find it in my IDE. 
Important Step : File > Settings > [Build,Execution,Deployment] > Debugger > Live Edit
select [Track changes in files compiled to JavaScript, HTML and CSS] > Apply&OK